# What commands can I use to see the detail of the <clinit> of some class of Java?

Tags: java, jvm

When I see the JVM specification, it says every class has at most one class initialization method and that is the 'clinit', so I think we should have some commands to see how this method was encoded in the .class file.

At first I thought using javap would be OK, but I didn't find it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javap` command displays the `<init>` and `<clinit>` methods ... though it doesn't use those names for them.  (See the `public Test();` and `static {};` "methods" below.)

Alternatively, you could also use another disassembler.  For example Krakatau will display the internal names `"<init>"` and `"<clinit>"` in its output.

> I had always thought there was a method name `<clinit>` in the `.class` file.

You are correct.  Those names will be present in the `.class` file representation of the methods.   And you can see the internal method names `<init>` and `<clinit>` in the constant table printed by `javap`.

It is just that the implementers of `javap` have *chosen* to not display those method names in the method section.  They have used a different notation.

(Why?  My guess is that they *thought* it would be easier for *most* people to understand the javap output if they did it that way!   Were they right?  I don't know, but it is moot anyway.)

---

```
$ cat Test.java 
public class Test {
  static String foo = "hello";
}


$ javap -p -c -s -v Test
Classfile /tmp/Test.class
  Last modified Feb 23, 2019; size 293 bytes
  MD5 checksum 724ea13308a150d0cc5730edcf4db616
  Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #5.#15         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = String             #16            // hello
   #3 = Fieldref           #4.#17         // Test.foo:Ljava/lang/String;
   #4 = Class              #18            // Test
   #5 = Class              #19            // java/lang/Object
   #6 = Utf8               foo
   #7 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/String;
   #8 = Utf8               <init>
   #9 = Utf8               ()V
  #10 = Utf8               Code
  #11 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #12 = Utf8               <clinit>
  #13 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #14 = Utf8               Test.java
  #15 = NameAndType        #8:#9          // "<init>":()V
  #16 = Utf8               hello
  #17 = NameAndType        #6:#7          // foo:Ljava/lang/String;
  #18 = Utf8               Test
  #19 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  static java.lang.String foo;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_STATIC

  public Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0

  static {};
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: ldc           #2                  // String hello
         2: putstatic     #3                  // Field foo:Ljava/lang/String;
         5: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 2: 0
}
SourceFile: "Test.java"
```